# Solenoid with 3mm stroke and ~1ms response time possible?

Tags: electrical-engineering, mechanisms, electromagnetism, pistons

I need to extend and retract a needle as fast as possible with dwell time while retracted, while one option I really like would be to use [Scotch Yoke with dwell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SCbTB50csM&ab_channel=mekanizmalar). However that would mean the stroke and dwell times are a fixed ratio where as ideally they would be independent leading me to look at linear actuators.

My question as stated above is if a solenoid could be made to respond in the 1ms range? The few solenoid data sheets I have viewed that bother with reaction times are ball parked around 10ms - though I presume these times could be shaved to some degree by preloading to counteract the return spring and reversing current to speed up desaturation of core (anyone got any information on how much this could save?) or do I need something more advanced such as voice coil, or ???

[I am looking to put around 1N of force behind the needle.]

Comment: These solenoid datasheets give the travel with no load: https://disti-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/testco-inc/files/datasheets/4000.pdf

https://www.testco-inc.com/ledex#Low%20Profile